# How can I found the longest way on board?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I'm making some simple game AI now.
But I am blocked at this problem now.

First of all, Sorry for my bad English.

I have random 2 dimension bool grid, which 'true' is "Can move", 'false' is "Can't move". A player is at somewhere of bool grid, and the player can move only 4 directions(up, down, left, right). If the player moved, a cell of the previous position became 'false'.
If four directions of the player are all blocked, Moving is End.

In this Situation, how can I get the longest way, and the biggest move count?

I hope you have a nice day!:D

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by **longest way** and **biggest move count**, if possible please provide some examples too?

Comment: @Ramya Ramanathan
My English is Bad, so that is my best....sorry

Comment: I believe this is akin to finding the longest simple path in an undirected cyclic graph, which is NP-hard (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).

Comment: If I read your question correctly, you're trying to find the longest non-intersecting path through an orthogonal maze.  This problem is covered well on line (including Stack Overflow), far more completely than we can answer it here.  If you search for "longest path maze", you should get plenty of useful hits.

Comment: First of all this is not 'AI'. Its an algorithm. If this output is used to derive another result then its an AI. please check this link : https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/artificial-intelligence-vs-machine-learning-vs-deep-learning

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use backtracking technique because it try all possible way in the bord

the back tracking is depend on recursion i can give you an algorithm to be implement if you interesting in backtracking